# Django: Cookie set to expire in 30 seconds is actually expiring in 30 minutes?

Tags: python, django, cookies

This is my code:

```
def update_session(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() or not request.method=='POST':
       return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
    user_id = request.POST.get('u')
    hr = set_terminal_cookie(user_id)
    return hr

def set_terminal_cookie(user_id):
    print 'set_terminal_cookie'
    hr = HttpResponse('ok')
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    expiry_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    print expiry_time
    hr.set_cookie('user_id', user_id, expiry_time)
    return hr
```

This is the log output:

```
set_terminal_cookie
2011-04-05 23:16:36.706624
2011-04-05 23:17:06.706806
```

However, if I then check the 'user_id' cookie in Firefox, the 'Expires' date is:

```
Tue Apr 5 23:50:07 2011
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `max_age` parameter with a number of seconds instead of using `expires`; it'll calculate `expires` for you.  The problem with your `datetime.now()` may be that you're not using UTC (you can use `datetime.utcnow()` instead).

```
hr.set_cookie('user_id', user_id, max_age=30)
```

Moral of the story: [read the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie); it explains both that you need to use a UTC `datetime` object and describes `max_age`.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to read the documentation, but for some reason it wasn't going in...

Answer (score 1):

For those that are running in to the same problem with signed cookies, you have to use [`get_signed_cookie()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_signed_cookie) with the `max_age` attribute. I tried setting it with the [`set_signed_cookie()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_signed_cookie) method, but that doesn't work when fetching it again.

So this won't expire your cookie:

```
cookie_max_age = settings.TWO_FACTOR_REMEMBER_USER_SECONDS
response.set_signed_cookie('key', max_age=cookie_max_age)
```

But when fetching it like the following, it should work (with and without setting a `max_age` on the cookie):

```
cookie_max_age = 3600
cookie = request.get_signed_cookie('key', max_age=cookie_max_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
hr.set_cookie('user_id', user_id, max_age=30)
```

The max_age parameter is the number of seconds that you want the cookie to last.

Answer (score 0):

in Django, you can set max_age argument.
[In Django 4.1 max_age should be a timedelta object, an integer number of seconds, or None (default) if the cookie should last only as long as the client’s browser session. If expires is not specified, it will be calculated.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie)