# Django, setting cookie

Tags: django, cookies

[Django: Cookie set to expire in 30 seconds is actually expiring in 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559271/433570) does

```
hr = HttpResponse('ok')
hr.set_cookie('user_id', user_id, max_age=30)
```

while https://stackoverflow.com/a/25179642/433570 does

```
request.session[user_id] = True
```

And both says we are setting `cookie`.

What's the difference between the two?
Can I set the expiration with the `request.session` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, cookies are intended to be stored in client side while sessions are stored in server-side (unless you're using [cookie based session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#cookie-session-backend)).

Users can clear *http cookies* from their browsers but they can't do anything about the *sessions* on your server. [Clearing sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store) is up you and your settings. There are some [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#settings) you can use to determine their age like `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`. For http cookies it's possible to set [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes) like `max_age`, `expires`.

Choosing which one to use depends on your requirements; are you going to store sensitive data, is permanence important etc.

References:

- [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)
- [Django request-response methods including set_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#id3)
- [Wikipedia HTTP cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Thank you, one question though, Even though user can't edit sessions on my server, he can delete the session key which points to the server session data in his browser cookie? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, user can still clear browser cookies, but can't manipulate the values if they are stored in server side session.